# Automatically naming the function and the contents of the function with the value in the pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, function, label, snorkel

I am looking for data containing specific words through **snorkel**(https://www.snorkel.org/use-cases/01-spam-tutorial) from dataframe **df**.

**df**

| not_matter | Text |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | hallo Apple |
| 222 | Berry and bb |
| 333 | bb and Candy |

Now i have a pandas dataframe **df_wordlist** where column_1 and 2 are different words and column_3 is a combination of columns 1 and 2.

df_wordlist

| Column_1 | Column_2 | Column_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aa | Apple | aa_Apple |
| aa | Berry | aa_Berry |
| aa | Candy | aa_Candy |
| bb | Apple | bb_Apple |
| bb | Berry | bb_Berry |
| bb | Candy | bb_Candy |

I now need to define different label functions, and I want the names of these functions to be the values in column_3, and the contents of the funtion to be the values in column_1 and column_2.

```
@labeling_function()
def aa_Apple(x):
    return FOERD if re.search(r"\b(?=.*aa.*)(?=.*Apple.*)\b|\b(?=.*Apple.*)(?=.*aa.*)\b", df.Text, flags=re.I) else ABSTAIN

@labeling_function()
def aa_Berry(x):
    return FOERD if re.search(r"\b(?=.*aa.*)(?=.*Berry.*)\b|\b(?=.*Berry.*)(?=.*aa.*)\b", df.Text, flags=re.I) else ABSTAIN 

.......the other 3 functions.....

@labeling_function()
def bb_Candy(x):
    return FOERD if re.search(r"\b(?=.*bb.*)(?=.*Candy.*)\b|\b(?=.*Candy.*)(?=.*bb.*)\b", df.Text, flags=re.I) else ABSTAIN
```

I tried to do this with loop but it didn't work.

```
for i in range(len(df_wordlist)):
    label_name = str(df_wordlist.iloc[i,-1])
    label_word1 = str(df_wordlist.iloc[i,0])
    label_word2 = str(df_wordlist.iloc[i,1])

    @labeling_function()
    def label_name(x):
        return FOERD if re.search(r"\b(?=.*label_word1.*)(?=.*label_word2.*)\b|\b(?=.*label_word2.*)(?=.*label_word1.*)\b", df, flags=re.I) else ABSTAIN
```

I want through a loop generate so many label functions, like the length of the df_wordlist.

Latter I need to put all the functions in a list to be invoked, like:

```
function_ls = [aa_Apple, aa_Berry, bb_Candy]
```

In a loop, it should be:

```
for i in range(len(df_wordlist)):
    label_name = str(df_wordlist.iloc[i,-1])
    function_ls= []
    function_ls = function_ls.append(label_name)
    return function_ls
```

Comment: This looks like a bad idea - how would you refer to these functions later? It would probably be better to put them in a dict.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I need to put all the functions in a list to be invoked, like 

function_ls = [aa_Apple, aa_Berry, bb_Candy]

In a loop, it should be:

for i in range(len(df_wordlist)):
    label_name = str(df_wordlist.iloc[i,-1])
    function_ls= []
    function_ls = function_ls.append(label_name)
    return function_ls

Or Can you tell me more about "put them in a dict"? Thanks